# Warning ruby message when starting a new console in Linux

Tags: rvm, ruby-2.7

I don't know why I'm seeing this message every time I split my console with *terminator* in Ubuntu the ruby version is 3.3.0, which is installed in the upper file *documents*, so when I want to switch to 2.7.0 version with the command *`rvm use 2.7.0`* I see this message.

> Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/santiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin is not at first place.
> Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. search for PATH=... entries.
> You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
> To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby 3.3.0
> To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.

[image]

I have installed ruby with **rvm 1.29.12 (latest).**
I add in my ruby project a  *.ruby-version* file with 2.7.0 inside this file to automatically change the ruby version when I go into this project but didn't work and I have to manually change the version after this I can keep working normally.

I tried to follow the instructions in the message but that didn't work and re installed all the ruby versions but that didn't work.
I want to know how solve it and why this is happening if it's possible.

Comment: Images that contain text should be augmented by the text they contain or replaced by that text. By adding the text your make it easier for your question to be found, and make it possible for a wider range of people to provide you an answer.